# Can I daemonize a golang process without external tools?

Tags: go, daemon

I've seen many different suggestions for how to daemonize an application written in Go, including using upstart or init.d.  Why not just do it yourself though?  It seems like the steps are simple enough:

- Fork and exit parent
- Change file mode mask
- Create a unique session id
- Change current working directory
- Close file descriptors

([source](http://www.linuxprofilm.com/articles/linux-daemon-howto.html#s3))

So why not just do this in your program, rather than depending on third party software to do a simple task for you?

Comment: `init.d` is just daemon manager, it does not daemonise. All daemons on Debian should play nice with `init.d`. As to why it seems to be hard, see [this open issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/227).

Answer (score 1):

Messing directly with fork() from a Go program is perilous. A typical deamonize implementation based on an equivalent C program is not safe.

You may be interested by the approach used by the following package:
https://github.com/VividCortex/godaemon